# Where should API calls take place in React?

Tags: reactjs, api, asynchronous, react-redux, redux-thunk

Good day,

I am using react-redux and redux-thunk.

The sample code below.

**projects.jsx**

```
const fetch = async () => {
    const { data: projects } = await getProjects()
    dispatch(storeProjects(projects))
}

const projects = useSelector(state => state.projects)
console.log(projects)
```

**/actions/projects.js**

```
export const storeProjects = (projects) => {
    return {
        type: 'STORE_PROJECTS',
        projects
    }
}
```

**/reducers/index.js**

```
const projects = (state = {}, { type, projects }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case 'STORE_PROJECTS':
            state.projects = projects
            return state

        default: return state
    }
}

export default projects
```

**The problem is**

`console.log(projects)` can't print projects

while doing this in **not asynchronous** way

```
const fakeProjects = [ { project: 'fakeProject '}]
dispatch(storeProjects(fakeProjetcs ))

const projects = useSelector(state => state.projects)
console.log(project) // it can now print
```

Further details

**App.js**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import ReduxThunk from "redux-thunk"
import reducers from './redux/reducers';

function App() {
  const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk))

  return <>
    <Provider store={store}>
//children
    </Provider>
  </>
```

}

**/reducers/index.js**

```
import projects from './projects'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'

export default combineReducers({ projects })
```

Comment: We need a bit more information than this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey good day, I did some details to make some clarity, I am hoping that you can reopen this? thank you